# Skip certain directories with rm -rf

Tags: bash, rm

I would like to know if and how it is possible to skip certain directories during an `rm -rf` operation.

So for example, this location contains the following subfolders (not really this is just for example):

```
foo
bar
elf
qrs
```

During my script which executes `rm -rf *` in this directory, I would like to know if it is possible to (for example) skip deletion of `elf`.

Normally, I could just pass each directory to the command with `rm -rf foo bar qrs`, however my scenario is, since this is in a script for many different systems, every system will have different folders. For example, system 1 may contain these:

```
foo
bar
elf
qrs
```

While system2 may contain these:

```
ubt
dbn
arc
elf
gnt
```

I would like the `rm -rf` command to be the same for both; deleting everything apart from `elf`.

Is this in any way possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use " find . | grep -v "elf" | xargs rm -rf " in the parent directory wherein you want to delete items recursively.

Comment: Is the `find -type d ! -name "elf" -delete` may be the option for your case?

Comment: @danielleontiev Yes. Quite concise and useful. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.putorius.net/run-rm-command-but-exclude-one-file.html) there is no built exclude functionality to `rm`. However, the article details multiple methods using some shell commands to achieve the same result.

The first seems most applicable for you:
Delete all files except the file called important.txt:
`rm !(important.txt)`

Comment: Thanks, this works 100%. I did add `-rf` to the command to make: `rm -rf !(elf)`, and it works.

Comment: But the question is about deleting folders, and not files, am I getting something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible solutions:

```bsh
find -type d ! -name "elf" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. Shame it won't let me accept 2 answers. But I've upvoted it :)